# Why does the code(funtional) for the hook keep rendering? (compared to Class)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-lifecycle

I just started react...

This code is simply rendered after 3 seconds using Boolean value.

But the code below keeps rendering.. rendering.. rendering... almost every three seconds.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  setTimeout(() => {
    setIsLoading(!isLoading);
  }, 3000);

  return <h1>{isLoading ? "Loading" : "we are ready"}</h1>;
};

export default App;
```

But this code works well. What is the reason?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
      });
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.isLoading ? "Loading..." : "we are ready"}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function component is called on every render. That means the timeout is created on every re-render after a state change as well, when implemented like in your first example. To use the component lifecycle, you should use the `useEffect` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  // Set a timeout ONCE when the component is rendered for the first time
  // The second argument [] signifies that nothing will trigger the effect during re-renders
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, [])

  return <h1>{isLoading ? "Loading" : "we are ready"}</h1>;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are initializing isLoading with true value in the state. and whenever the state is changed functional components rerenders, and it doesn't happen in Class-based component as you have used the component life cycle method. You should use "useEffect" in the functional component.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(!isLoading);
    }, 3000);
  });
```

you can read about it here   https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer from MubtadaNaqvi will unfortunately result in infinite loop. You should apply useEffect properly:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(isLoading => !isLoading);
    }, 1000);
  }, [])
```

Comment: This won't work either, since the setter doesn't take a function as argument.

Comment: You can provide a prevState in setState and that's what I did. `setIsLoading(false)` would be another option.

Comment: I see, I thought that only worked for class-based components.

Comment: Doing so you would avoid useEffect linting complaint that it has missing dependency isLoading

Comment: Fair enough. Though, in this case, simply setting it to `false` might make more sense